# How can I get a value from a table using BeautifulSoup, when that table has multiple values under the same class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, yahoo-finance

I am trying to grab the Enterprise Value/EBITDA from yahoo finance. Let's say that our stock is Tesla.
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/key-statistics?p=TSLA is the link.
Whenever I try to sort by class in BeautifulSoup, I receive the first result in the table.
How can I get the Enterprise Value/EBITDA with BeutifulSoup and using HTML tags and such?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would personally

1. Grab the table as a whole, separate the rows into a list.
2. Search each row for the string "Enterprise Value/EBITDA"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing error-prone webscraping yourself, you can simply use the [yfinance api](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance), that provides the needed information.

You could try the following:

```
import yfinance as yf

info = yf.Ticker("TSLA").get_info()
print(f"Enterprise Value/EBITDA: {info['enterpriseToEbitda']}")

>>Enterprise Value/EBITDA: 111.121
```

If you want to go down the 'bs4' lane, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.60 Safari/537.36'}
url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/key-statistics?p=TSLA'
req=requests.get(url,headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(req,'lxml')
table=soup.findAll("table", {"class": "Bdcl(c)"})

data =pd.read_html(str(table))[0].set_index('Unnamed: 0')

print(data.loc['Enterprise Value/EBITDA'])


>>As of Date: 3/24/2022Current    106.36
>>12/31/2021                      305.48
>>9/30/2021                       279.34
>>6/30/2021                       324.16
>>3/31/2021                       508.47
>>12/31/2020                      545.52
>>Name: Enterprise Value/EBITDA, dtype: object
```